# Object.create works new() doesn't

Tags: javascript, object

Having this:

```
sillyObject = {
    init: function init(sillySettings) {
        name = sillySettings.name
    }
};

sillyObject.showAlert = function(x) {
    return alert(x);
};
```

When I run this code:

```
var sillyvar  = new sillyObject()
sillyvar.init(mySettings);
silly.showAlert("silly!");
```

I get an error but instead if I run the same thing using Object.create it runs..

```
var sillyvar  = Object.create(sillyObject);
sillyvar.init(mySettings);
silly.showAlert("silly!");
```

Any (silly) help will be appreciated.

Comment: This behavior is by design.  `new` doesn't do that.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: You're [leaking the `name` variable](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

new and Object.create are two fundamentally different things.

`new` is going to expect to be followed by a function, and if not (as you saw) it will give you an error. That is because new expects to call a constructor function and then use that as a basis for a new execution context. During that context, the function has `this` bound to the scope of the execution context. Once the function is done executing it returns the `this` value which usually has had some data attached to it. In your example, that would look like this:

```
function sillyObject() {}
sillyObject.prototype.init = function(sillySettings) {
   //perhaps you wanted to attach this name to the sillyObject?
   name = sillySettings.name;
   //which would look like this
   this.name = sillySettings.name;
   //because `this` here refers to the object context (remember?)
};
sillyObject.prototype.showAlert = function(x){
   return alert(x);//returning alert simply returns undefined (not sure why this is used here)
};
```

and then you could use new, it would create the execution context using the constructor and then attach the prototype and you would end up with a new instance of sillyObject (all instances would be different).

```
var sO = new sillyObject();
sO.init(mySettings);
sO.showAlert("silly!");
```

`Object.create()` on the other hand is expecting an object as an argument (which is why your version worked here). It will create a new object using that object argument as a template basically. Or as [MDN explains it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) "The Object.create() method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties". This basically creates a copy if nothing else is done with the Object, and that is why the alert worked here but not in the `new` version.

Comment: "*…the function has `this` bound to a new object (typically referred to as a function object):…*". The object created by *new* is an Object object, not a Function. I think it's more common to call it an instance of the constructor or just a new object.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your answer. It seems to me that you're saying that the object created by `new someFn` and bound to its *this* is a Function. That would only happen in the case of `new Function()`, which doesn't seem relevant here (also noting that host object constructors can create any kind of object: *new Option*, *new Image*, *new XMLHttpRequest*, etc.).

Comment: @RobG - No, that is not what I was trying to say. I removed the link to Function objects because that was an incorrect response to your first comment. `this` is bound inside of the execution context created by using `new someFn()`. The component is named `ThisBinding` and is one of 3 components of the execution context. The execution context *is* the object. It is where the variable and lexical environments are, and that is where the binding of this occurs. An object is just at a very simple level a memory reference which contains other references.

Comment: My question was basically if Object.create() can be used as object constructor...if not was the proper way to make an object constructor?
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you tried doing `new sillyObject()`, the error you get is `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` since `sillyObject` is an object and not a function.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3658673/509710) gives a good overview on the `new` keyword.

`Object.create` does not do the same thing as `new`. It will create a new object with `sillyObject` as the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

`sillyObject` is a Object not a function. `new` will create a new instance of a function. You probably want to use `this` or just `.prototype`

```
var sillyObject = function () {
    this.sillySettings = {};
}

sillyObject.prototype = {
    init     : function (name) {
        this.sillySettings.name = name;
    },

    showAlert: function (x) { 
       return alert(x);
    }
};

var silly = new sillyObject(); 
silly.init('foo');
silly.showAlert('bar');
```

`this.sillySettings` isn't a function so we don't keep it in the prototype. We can keep `init` and `showAlert` in the prototype. We use prototype because when using `new` we use `sillyObject()` so imagine the variable silly being replaced this `sillyObject()` showing why we use prototype because `silly` is instantiated as a function.